# Reset text formatting in QTextEdit after space

Tags: c++, qt, qwidget, qtextedit

Are there good solution to reset text formatting (e.g. **bold**) after press Space button for QTextEdit?

Example of case:

**boldText** notBoldText // After press Space button text is not bold anymore

---

For example, I can use QWidget::eventFilter(...) and check inside

```
if (key == Qt::Key_Space) { ... }
```

But it looks bad.

It's how I set formatting now:

```
    QTextCursor cursor = textCursor();
    if (!cursor.hasSelection())
        return;

    QTextCharFormat fmt;
    fmt.setFontWeight(cursor.charFormat().font().bold() ? QFont::Normal : QFont::DemiBold);

    cursor.mergeCharFormat(format);
    mergeCurrentCharFormat(format);
```

Comment: This is exactly what event filters are good for. Why do you think it looks bad?

Comment: @V.K.authorofHiFile Bc I though there is some another solution or "flag". But okey, if no one will answer, then I will answer with my eventFilter() solution

Comment: The question however is how you will write a space in your text edit... Or do you expect your text to contain no spaces?

Comment: @V.K.authorofHiFile It's about: how to reset text formatting (that you set to text before) after pressing Space button. But I think now after your comment that eventFilter() solution is ok